# PHP - ¿Cómo instanciar una clase dentro de sí misma?

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Tengo una clase User, la cual tiene algunos métodos estáticos para buscar usuarios en la base de datos. Pero también tiene un método para crear un nuevo objeto User si se ha encontrado un usuario por su id.

User class:

```
class User {

        private $id;
        private $username;
        private $password;
        private $firstName;
        private $lastName;

        public function __construct($id, $username, 
                                    $password, $firstName,
                                    $lastName) {
            $self->id = $id;
            $self->username = $username;
            $self->password = $password;
            $self->firstName = $firstName;
            $self->lastName = $lastName;
        }

        public function GetId() {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function GetUsername() {
            return $this->username;
        }
        public function GetFirstName() {
            return $this->firstName;
        }
        public function GetLastName() {
            return $this->lastName;
        }

        public static function GetAllUsers() {
            $result = Database::Query("SELECT * FROM users");
            return $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public static function FindUserById($id) {
            $result = Database::Query("SELECT * FROM users
                                       WHERE id = $id
                                       LIMIT 1");
            return $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public static function CreateUserObject($id) {

            $foundUser = self::FindUserById($id);

            if ($foundUser) {
                $user = new User($foundUser["id"], $foundUser["username"],
                                 $foundUser["password"], $foundUser["first_name"],
                                 $foundUser["last_name"]);

                return $user;
            }

        }

    }
```

El problema es que al invocar el método CreateUserObject, tengo esta advertencia:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\gallery-system\admin\includes\classes\user.php on line
>   14.

Si elimino el constructor, instancio la clase como
 `new User()`

y asigno directamente cada atributo, por ejemplo:

```
$this->username = $foundUser["username"];
```

funciona, pero no me parece la mejor práctica.

¿Como podría hacer esto?

Gracias.

Comment: si no estoy mal la advertencia se produce porq si no entra en el condional del metodo `CreateUserObject` no returnara nada, entoces deberias poner algun return null al final para este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia Samir.

Yo también lo había pensado, aunque no había intentado cambiarlo. Sin embargo, lo acabo de hacer, colocando un return null despues del if, y la advertencia continúa apareciendo.

También, no es solo la advertencia sino que el objeto no ha sido creado, o al menos no como lo esperaba.

Comment: en el constructor cambia `$self->` por `$this->` para usar `self::` las `private`deberían ser `static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más óptima de hacer esto sería usando `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` el cual:

> Devuelve una nueva instancia de la clase solicitada, haciendo
>   corresponder las columnas del conjunto de resultados con los nombres
>   de las propiedades de la clase, y llamando al constructor después, a
>   menos que también se proporcione `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`. Si
>   fetch_style incluye `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` (por ejemplo,
>   `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`), entonces el nombre de la
>   clase se determina a partir del valor de la primera columna.
>
> <sub>- [`fetch` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)</sub>

Prueba a escribir tu método así:

```
    public static function FindUserById($id) {
        $result = Database::Query("SELECT * FROM users
                                   WHERE id = $id
                                   LIMIT 1");
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');

        /*¡Aquí ya tendrás tu objeto, y con datos!*/
        $objUser = $result->fetch();
        var_dump($objUser);
        return $objUser;
    }
```

Lo que retornará el método será una instancia de la clase donde cada columna del `SELECT` será mapeada a las propiedades de la clase.

Ya que lo tienes aquí puedes prescindir de `CreateUserObject` y usar los datos directamente... Si de todos modos lo quieres usar como lo tienes ahora, sería tan simple como:

```
    public static function CreateUserObject($id) {
        /*Quizá convendría establecer controles de NULL o vacío aquí o en el otro método*/
        $objUser = self::FindUserById($id);
        return $objUser;

    }
```

---

#### Otros problemas en el código

Para establecer los valores de los miembros `private` de la clase debes usar `$this` en vez de `$self`:

```
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
```

Aunque en realidad, me atrevería a decir que en este caso lo mejor sería tener un constructor vacío y llenar los valores de los miembros de otro modo (por ejemplo mediante métodos `setter`. Esa decisión final depende ya de tu contexto y del uso que piensas dar a la clase.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! En cuanto tenga tiempo la probaré, pero desde ya me parece excelente, especialmente porque el método mapea las columnas, eso era algo que quería hacer pero no tenía idea de como hacerlo.

Con respecto a mi uso de $self, si, la verdad es que no lo había notado, uso $this, pero jugue mucho con self buscando una solución y termine usandolo para los atributos.

Hasta entonces había decidido dejar el constructor vacío y asignar los atributos con un forEach.

La intención de esto es aprender, no es algo profesional :)

Comment: Increíble solución. Muchísimas gracias, ¡ya la estoy usando!
Te dejo un pastebin con la clase actualmente: https://pastebin.com/CQNDWiSs

Comment: nota extra: el warning es porque `$self` no existe en ese contexto, es decir crea `$self` como `default object` vacío para poder asignarle `$id` a la propiedad `id`, mismo warning aparecería con `$solf->id = $id`